# google colab python recursion error is it bug?

Tags: python, recursion, google-colaboratory

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

this is code and result came

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
21
```

why '21' came 2-times?
I also executed it on 'VS Code', 'PyCharm' but these are not include last '21'
what's wrong??

Code and result:
[image]

Comment: The first `21` comes from the `print` call.  The second is just the return value of the function being displayed by the interpreter.  If you don't want to see it, you can assign the result of the function call to a variable.

Comment: Then why VS Code has result of '''1
3
6
10
15
21'''??

Comment: Because you're probably invoking it through a file.  You'd see the same thing with just a single number like `123`.  Does VS Code display it if you type it?  Your interactive interpreter does.  Now that you know where it's coming from, surely you can work out the details for yourself.

Comment: Aha! thanks a lot. Would you let me know how can I print only one '21' ? (correnting the top of the code)

Comment: I already told you in my first comment.  Assign the result to a variable.  E.g. `val = tri_recursion(6)`.  Then there will be no value to display at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)   # Explicitly print the reults
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)    # Implicitly display the expression value
```

Your IDE displays the value of any expression that isn't "falsey".  Your function returns the value `21` to the main program.  Since you made the call as a simple expression, your IDE evaluates that expression and displays the value; that's where you get the second `21`.  If you want to suppress it, try assigning the value -- which is proper practice, anyway.

```
do_not_show = tri_recursion(6)
```